# In MATLAB, how to create diagonal with integers and zeros everywhere else using nxn matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

I have to create an *n x n* matrix with 199, 409, 619,....210n-11 down the diagonal and zeros everywhere else.

Here is my M file so far:

```
function A = MyDiagMatrix(n)
     A = zeros(n,n);
     for i =199:210:210n-11
          eye(i);
     end
end
```

what am I doing wrong? Any help would be great!

Comment: wait, so you just want to create a matrix with N x N size and on the diagonal its going to be all zeros? whats with  199:210:210n-11

Comment: Rook solves your problem, Azim explains how it works. Note also that `210n` does not work in MATLAB, instead of the implied multiplication you need to explicitly say `210*n`.

Answer (score 7):

First your function initializes the matrix, *A*, but does nothing with it after.  You need to modify the entry of *A* for your function to return anything more than the zero matrix.

You could use MATLAB's function *diag* which creates a diagonal matrix from a vector. for example

```
d=1:n; %# create vector 1,2,...,n
A = diag(d) %# create diagonal matrix with entries A(i,i) = i with i=1,2,...,n;
```

modify the input vector *d* to suite your needs

Answer (score 3):

If you want it as a function ...

```
function [ a ] = MyDiagonalMatrix( n )
a = diag(199:210:210*n-11);
end
```

p.s. The credit for this should really go to Azim.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function you need :

```
@( n ) diag(199:210:210*n-11)
```

And the e.g. of calling it:

```
MyDiagonalMatrix(3)
```

Actual test in MATLAB R2012a:

```
>> MyDiagonalMatrix = @( n ) diag(199:210:210*n-11)

MyDiagonalMatrix = 

    @(n)diag(199:210:210*n-11)

>> MyDiagonalMatrix(3)

ans =

   199     0     0
     0   409     0
     0     0   619

>> MyDiagonalMatrix(5)

ans =

         199           0           0           0           0
           0         409           0           0           0
           0           0         619           0           0
           0           0           0         829           0
           0           0           0           0        1039
```

They meets your requirement: 
"an n x n matrix with 199, 409, 619,....210n-11 down the diagonal and zeros everywhere else."

Hope that helps!